# How to add additional variables to the existing properties in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

The `Button` component in AntD have a property of `type` that accepts the variables `primary` `dashed` `ghost` `danger`. How can I add a `type=success` where success would be defined with a particular colour within my `.less` file? I'm not referring to the examples of AntD where they point out how to modify the pre-existing primary colour but rather creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new component which will use a button component from Ant Design.

```
import { Button } from 'antd';

const antdTypes = ['primary', 'dashed', 'ghost', 'danger'];

function ExtendedButton({ type, ...rest }) {
  if (antdTypes.inclues(type))
    return <Button type={type} {...rest} />
  else
    return <Button className={`button--${type}`} {...rest} />
}
```

You'll be able to create CSS/LESS class `button--success` for example and then pass second part (M from BEM) of classname as a prop

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend it as

```js
import { Button as BaseButton, ButtonProps } from 'antd';
import { ButtonType as BaseButtonType } from 'antd/lib/button';
import React from 'react';

type ButtonType = BaseButtonType | 'success' | 'warning';

export default function Button(props: Omit<ButtonProps, 'type'> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLElement> & { type?: ButtonType }) {
  return <BaseButton {...(props as any)} />;
}
```

and then only style classes `ant-btn-success`, `ant-btn-warning`